# Is there a benifit to "wishful thinking"?

Tags: wishful, thinking

Is there a benefit to "wishful thinking" ?

not like in a very deluded way    -

but like if i think about meditating a lot during the day -  or getting money to also give others and aid practice

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a benifit to “wishful thinking”?

I would not exactly call that wishful thinking but rather the results from practicing the path correctly (in this life or previous lives).

*Wanting to meditate or wanting to aid other beings* spring from wholesome intentions, i.e. right intentions of *good-will*. These are path factors.

Right intentions-> actions that are based in *non-greed, non-hatred, non-delusion*, are bound to create wholesome future resultants.

So the benefit would be the fact that wholesome actions lead to wholesome results. Experiencing and undertanding that through the practice of insight meditation is a huge benefit. When the mind experiences this over and over it begins to understand causality and how suffering comes to be.

If you observe how craftsmen build a house you will see that they lay the bricks layer by layer. The first layer is the foundational layer. The layer everything else has to be based upon.

In the practice one of the foundational bricks is *right intentions*.

Answer (score 1):

Can we stop adversities and yearnings by wishful thinking / wishful prayer, wherein one humbly or earnestly asks a higher power to provide something beyond oneself? – things such as Oh! Don’t let me go to decay and death - by such imploring can we stop it?  No. You cannot stop aging by reciting a thousand verses of blessings.  Can we prevent death? No.  Can you avoid sickness by offering a token offerings?  No.  Supreme Buddha’s Dhamma says “Understand, come and see the principle causing dukkha or pain”.  When this is, this will be.  Hence when this is born, this is born.  This is the noble principle; noble research method that will ennoble. Supreme Buddha says, a noble disciple makes inquiry wisely about dukkha or pain.

Comment: what about may i meditate more  ?

Comment: Yes. Do loving kindness meditation. You will get a wholesome complexion, replacing unwholesome bodily states that came up from unwholesome roots. Then illness & disease will purge out of the body. Start with oneself and gradually and mindfully purge  mind of hatred (dosa) and cultivate loving kindness (metta) in the Mind and then resolve that it spreads through the entire body. Also do good to others, to counteract the bad effects of the past kammic activity by  present positive and wholesome acts. Also try to do IMPERMANENCE Meditation.

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear  -     what about the wishful thinking : "may i meditate more" ?

Comment: In Vajrayana Buddhism, It talks about ishta devata / fairy angels. There are Devas in the heavenly world who sometimes help humans. It is not a deity but an enlightened being who takes an interest in a person, or a past relative who has gone on to a higher plain. In this sense, you can meditate on -  it can be translated as on “meditational Deva / Devas.”